# Substitution in LINQ OrderBy

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have tried the following to modify the sort order in order to have the fields with `HeureDebut` sorted to the end when it is `00:00` but it does not work
Is there another method to achieve this?

```
Dim theCompetitions As List(Of competitions) = (From aCompetition In context.competitions 
            Where aCompetition.concour_id = idConcours 
            And aCompetition.isPublic = 1 
            And aCompetition.idMYMaster = 0 _
            Order By aCompetition.DateEpreuve, If(aCompetition.HeureDebut = "00:00", "99:99", aCompetition.HeureDebut), aCompetition.NoRef).ToList()
```

Comment: It what way does it "not work"? Do you want them at the end _of each `DateEpreuve` group_ or at the end of the entire collection?  The way you've got it now does the former.

Comment: I want to have the records where aCompetition.HeureDebut = "00:00" at the end of the list and not at the beginning. 
The request returns no record at all when I have "If(aCompetition.HeureDebut = "00:00", "99:99", aCompetition.HeureDebut)" in the order by clause, if I have just "aCompetition.HeureDebut", it returns the list but with the records where HeureDebut="00:00" at the beginning and I wish to have those records at the end